# AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'

Tags: apache-2.4, ldap, openldap, apache2

i have installed ldap and phpldapadmin 3 weeks ago and everything was good. yesterday i wanted to configure web server, so the web server works fine, and the command

```
service apache2 restart
```

it gives as result :

```
 * Restarting web server apache2                                         [ OK ]
```

but when i check the file   /var/log/apache2/error.log  i get :

```
[Mon Jan 09 23:07:56.392253 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 10447:tid 3074607744] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jan 09 23:07:56.392355 2017] [core:notice] [pid 10447:tid 3074607744] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

when this result appears in this file, i could not be able any more to access to my_IP_address/phpldapadmin, it gives as result 
"The requested URL /phpldapadmin/ was not found on this server. "

Also:

```
$ service apache2 status
* apache2 is running

$ pgrep apache
10642
10645
10646

$ telnet localhost 80
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.

$ ps -A | grep 'apache2'
 10642 ?        00:00:00 apache2
 10645 ?        00:00:00 apache2
 10646 ?        00:00:00 apache2
```

so any help ?

Comment: all you are showing is normal apache activity, the logs, the processes, yet you show nothing about the configuration you changed or the configuration you have which can indeed affect what's served and what not. Please consider adding all relevant info regarding your configuration instead of this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the OP has demonstrated a system working as designed.

Comment: @Hangin on in quiet desperation : you'd better read again what i'v posted ... i have a problem with phpldapadmin ..

Comment: I've read it carefully a couple of times. You have not provided any information that suggests the system is working in any way other than as expected.

Comment: related: https://serverfault.com/questions/607873/apache-is-ok-but-what-is-this-in-error-log-mpm-preforknotice

Answer (score 0):

That means your apache service is started, running, and working properly. Check the location where you installed phpldapadmin, it should be in "DocumentRoot" that you mentioned in http.conf file, or else create link to this path, then restart the apache service.

Comment: i couldn't find the file http.conf , so while searching i could find DocumentRoot in /etc/apache2/sites-available 000-default.conf , so now i changed this to : DocumentRoot /var/www because phpadmin do exists in this directory , so i restared apache2 but i still have this problem , i can not access to the 192.168.0.3/phpldapadmin :(

Comment: its httpd.conf file

Answer (score 0):

Apache seems working fine as other said.
I suggest you to check permissions about the folder where phpmyadmin is stored.
Check also if DocumentRoot or path where phpmyadmin is configured is really accessible.

Try create a new site where save a index.html file with "Hello" inside and try to provide it throw apache.